# Problema con bootsnap, en Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Tengo un proyecto hecho en Ruby on Rails. Estando en la línea de comando escribo y ejecuto el comando "rails server". Me sale lo siguiente:

```
Could not find gem 'wdm (>= 0.1.0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Hice caso al mensaje, y escribí y ejecute ese comando "bundle install".
El resultado fue el siguiente:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake 12.3.2
Using concurrent-ruby 1.1.5
Using i18n 1.6.0
Using minitest 5.11.3
Using thread_safe 0.3.6
Using tzinfo 1.2.5
Using activesupport 5.2.3
Using builder 3.2.3
Using erubi 1.8.0
Using mini_portile2 2.4.0
Using nokogiri 1.10.3 (x64-mingw32)
Using rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
Using crass 1.0.4
Using loofah 2.2.3
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.4
Using actionview 5.2.3
Using rack 2.0.7
Using rack-test 1.1.0
Using actionpack 5.2.3
Using nio4r 2.3.1
Using websocket-extensions 0.1.3
Using websocket-driver 0.7.0
Using actioncable 5.2.3
Using globalid 0.4.2
Using activejob 5.2.3
Using mini_mime 1.0.1
Using mail 2.7.1
Using actionmailer 5.2.3
Using activemodel 5.2.3
Using arel 9.0.0
Using activerecord 5.2.3
Using mimemagic 0.3.3
Using marcel 0.3.3
Using activestorage 5.2.3
Using public_suffix 3.0.3
Using addressable 2.6.0
Using io-like 0.3.0
Using archive-zip 0.12.0
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using autoprefixer-rails 9.5.1.1
Using bcrypt 3.1.12 (x64-mingw32)
Using bindex 0.7.0
Using msgpack 1.2.10 (x64-mingw32)
Fetching bootsnap 1.4.4
Installing bootsnap 1.4.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r
./siteconf20191111-14144-oc1pjz.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-x64-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `__strcat_chk'
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `__chk_fail'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:259: bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to
C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/bootsnap-1.4.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing bootsnap (1.4.4), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source
'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  bootsnap
```

Al parecer, hay un problema con el bootsnap. Es lo que me da a entender, cual es el problema exactamente, desconozco. 
Y nuevamente hice caso al mensaje ejecutando el comando que me indican ahí "gem install bootsnap -v '1.4.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'"
Resultado:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing bootsnap:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0 -r ./siteconf20191111-10600-w75ju8.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/ext/bootsnap
make "DESTDIR="
generating bootsnap-x64-mingw32.def
compiling bootsnap.c
linking shared-object bootsnap/bootsnap.so
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0x557): undefined reference to `__strcat_chk'
C:/Ruby25-x64/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: bootsnap.o:bootsnap.c:(.text+0xa07): undefined reference to `__chk_fail'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:259: bootsnap.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/bootsnap-1.4.4/gem_make.out
```

Buscando en internet, encontré varias veces lo mismo que recomendaban editar el gemfile y poner `gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false`. Pero lo hice, ejecute el `bundle install` y tampoco, me volvia a salir exactamente que lo que puse arriba. Soy muy MUY novato en lo que es Ruby y todo lo relacionado, asi que no se para donde ir, por así decirlo. No intente nada más, porque tampoco se que podria intentar.

¡Desde ya, muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar!

Comment: Una aclaración que no se si es relevante o no, pero la digo. En el archivo gemfile, antes salia lo siguiente `gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false` .Es decir, solo modifique los números.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citando [la documentación](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap#usage) de bootsnap:

> This gem works on macOS and Linux.

Al parecer ha habido algunos intentos por [hacerla compatible con windows](https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/52), pero no me parece que haya un soporte oficial. Las opciones que veo son:

- Al parecer algunos han logrado hacerla funcionar [fijándola a una versión específica](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516598/895789).
- Podrías volver a la versión que ya usabas, la `1.1.0`, o más bien, la que tenías en tu `Gemfile.lock`
- Hacer que no cargue en Windows haciendo los siguientes cambios:

.

```
# En Gemfile
gem 'bootsnap' unless (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)

# En config/boot.rb
require 'bootsnap/setup' unless (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)
```

- Por último, la que yo haría, pero que involucra más tiempo es cambiarte a un sistema Linux u OSX y ahorrarte dolores de cabeza como este y otros más que tendrás a futuro por estar usando ruby en windows, ya que gran parte del soporte está enfocado en sistemas *nix.

Comment: Hola, antes que nada gracias por responder. Viendo las opciones que me das y yo lo había pensado bastante, es la de usar Linux. Como veras, tengo Windows. Si no te es mucha molestia, me podrias aconsejar alguna máquina virtual o de donde descargar Linux para usarla en Windows.

Comment: Por cierto, había probado remover(comentar) la línea donde está lo de bootsnap. Pero dentro del propio proyecto, en un archivo boot.rb instancia a la gema. Por ende, da error despues. Así que si, la opción de Linux la veo como la más fiable y recomendable

Comment: @FerAvila revisa mi edición respecto a lo de tu archivo `boot.rb`. Respecto a que Linux usar, ufff, es todo un mundo de opciones eso. Si no tienes experiencia, te recomendaría que probaras con [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download), es una distro fácil de usar y hay demasiada información online para lo que necesites, incluído el instalarla junto con windows o en una VM. Recuerda que si la respuesta te ayudó, puedes marcarla como aceptada. Saludos

Comment: Para el  `gem 'bootsnap' unless (RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw|cygwin/)` tengo que tener instalado cygwin? Lo ejecute tanto fuera del proyecto como dentro y me sale lo siguiente: `"mingw" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.`

Comment: ¿estás ejecutando eso en cmd? eso tienes que ponerlo en tu archivo `Gemfile`, son instrucciones para ruby, no para tu shell.